# How to parse time intervals in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, time

I have time interval strings like `6:30 am – 2:30 pm` or `5:30–11:00 pm` (notice the omitted "pm" for the start time here) that I want to parse into Time objects in Ruby. Is there an elegant way to do that or do I have to catch all different cases manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the Chronic recommendation, alas, it doesn't provide interval parsing. Ended up using `Time.parse` and parsing the interval manually.

Answer (score 5):

http://chronic.rubyforge.org? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using a time library like [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) could help you?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is not the parsing of individual time strings but of the intervals, sometimes with omitted am/pm for the start time. Doesn't look like Chronic would be of help for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that does this. It'll take in an iso8601 format interval string (of the format start,end) and returns you the start and finish times from the interval.

```
iso8601_interval_text = "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
start, finish = iso8601_interval_text.split(/\//).map {|t| Time.parse(t)}
```